# How to access a sharepoint list using Msgraph in Swift

Tags: swift, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API and am wondering how to make a request like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/{listid}/items?expand=fields
```

I'm trying to reach a specific list on our SharePoint tenant. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to [register a new application](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2) that has permission to access SharePoint lists.
2. Once your app is registered and you have a client id, you would need to use an OAuth library like [MSAL for iOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) to authenticate a user.
3. Once you have an auth token acquired, you can issue calls to the Graph API using a networking library like [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). In each call, you will set a custom header called "Authorization" that has a value "Bearer " followed by your auth token.